# Can I run a MySQL query in a MySQL database field expression?

Tags: mysql, sql, expression

I'm wondering how to use expressions in a MySQL database (running `MySQL 5.0.88`). I recall from my dark MSAccess ages, that expressions where quite handy, but I never tried using a query in an expression. So:

Say I have a table with fields:

```
 dyn_usage  (True/False)
 actual_useage
```

First field indicates whether an item is billed on actual usage (or flat fee).

Could I then add an expression to the `actual_usage` field which contains a MySQL query (querying for the usage of the current_user like so:

```
 <!--- if dyn_usage = 1 --->
 SELECT COUNT( a.id ) AS no_of_instances
    FROM agents AS a
    WHERE a.verkaeufer = <cfqueryparam value = "#Session.loginId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="13">
    AND a.status = "active"
```

If I can store SQL expressions, does this include parameters (I'm running Coldfusion, hence the cfqueryparam).

Comment: Why would you want your database to handle template/view functions that it is not designed for? Sure a.verkaeufer and actual_useage can contain anything you need them to but just think of the data seek that has to happen every time that query is run. This would make for a very inefficient application design. Indexing this would just be just as inefficient too. My suggestion is to handle all view specifics at the app/view level (CFML) and let MySQL handle what it's good at, data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySql Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html) by having one regular table that contains `dyn_usage` and one view that selects `dyn_usage` from the regular table as the first column and calculates `actual_useage` as the second column.